# OpenLayers: map.eventsDiv disappears from version 2.12

Tags: openlayers

I am upgrading an existing web application to the latest version of OpenLayers. Our current version is 2.11 and we're upgrading to 2.13.1. One of the problems I cannot fix are our tooltips. The tooltips are showed by showing appended html by jQuery.show(). In the existing code, some html snippets are added to $(map.eventsDiv) by the following code:

```
$(map.eventsDiv).append('<div>...</div>');
```

In the source code of version 2.11, 'eventsDiv' gives 30 hits in 11 files. In all later versions, starting from 2.12-rc1, it gives 0 results. Most probably there is a new way to work with events, but I cannot find anything about removing eventsDiv on Google or on the release notes of 2.12 or 2.13.1. If there's someone who could help me with this, it would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by comparing some source files of both version 2.11 and 2.12-rc1 and found that where 2.11 uses `eventsDiv`, 2.12-rc1 uses `viewPortDiv`. I changed our existing code and now the tooltips work again.